# Conexão JDBC no Eclipse Neon

Tags: mysql, jdbc, conexão

Preciso de ajuda para adicionar o driver JDBC ao meu projeto feito no Eclipse versão Neon. Se possivel repassar uma classe de conexão para fazer teste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe o .jar do mysql connector e add ao Java build patch.

Segue Classe de conexão.

- método sem retorno conectar()
- método main para testar a chamada do método conectar()

```
 
    public class Conexao {
      public static void conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Carregou o Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seu_banco";
            String user = "seu_usuario";
            String password = "sua_senha";
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                System.out.println("Conectou");
                stm = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(" Não Conectou");
                Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Não Carregou o Driver");
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }       
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          conectar();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?